# (SPSS) I Need to split a large table containing (20,000 opiniton) into Longitude AND Latitude

Tags: spss

I am having trouble with SPSS 20
I need to split a table into longitude and latitude

I have tried the method below but get no where

NUMBER(CHAR.SUBSTR(geographicalCoords,1),CHAR.INDEX(geographicalCoords,',')-1),F10.6)

Answer (score 0):

Have a closer look at your line of code. You misplaced a bracket. If you remove it, your code should run perfectly fine.

(I assume that you line actually begins with a `COMPUTE` command.)

Comment: the method still does not work, even if i remove the bracket... Thanks for your help

Comment: @DMan Please edit your question (post) then, so that the following questions will answered. What exactly have you tried? (Please paste the whole line). What is the error message that you've got? Or if you didn't got an error message, what was your expected outcome, and what was the actual outcome of your procedure?